# Matching route from URL string

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I have a list of url, I want write a Laravel command to matching my current routes to get route name and route parameters. Is this possible?

I found out there is an Object at `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection` and has a method name is `match`, I could match the route from request. 
Now, I have to initial a Request from my urls, I tried to initial the Request and pass to the `match`, it's not work. I just get an NotFoundHttpException.

#### route

routes/web.php

```php
Route::get("/post/{post_id}", "PostController@post");
```

#### try to matching

```php
        $request = \Request::create("https://example.com/post/AABBCC");
        $routeCollection = new \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection();
        $route = $routeCollection->match($request);
```

Comment: You shouldn't create new RouteCollection isntance, just take it from application like this `$routes = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes();`

Comment: @IncOre, Thanks bro, you saved my life.